# How does DHTMLX Scheduler Call Data Method?

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

I'm using MVC4 and DHTMLX Scheduler. I am not understanding how DHTMLXScheduler.NET is triggering the Data() method.

```
 public ActionResult Data(string from, string to, string groupId)
        {
       return new SchedulerAjaxData(calendarModel);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! See the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If data loading is enabled, something like this will be added to the client side.

```
scheduler.load("/Scheduler/Data", "json");
```

By default, it will send ajax request to this action to load all the data.
As we can see from your code, you've also enabled dynamic loading. So it will add "from" and "to" parameters to get the request according to the view, which is currently showing.
Please see this article: http://scheduler-net.com/docs/loading-data.html#big_datasets